# SendInBlue - sib-api-v3-sdk sendTransacEmail() returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, email, sendinblue

I'm trying to send a transactional email with my new SendInBlue account and I keep receiving an error that simply says "Forbidden". I followed the example on SendInBlue's Nodejs docs to write this code:

```
const SibApiV3Sdk = require('sib-api-v3-sdk');

const defaultClient = SibApiV3Sdk.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure API key authorization: api-key
const apiKey = defaultClient.authentications['api-key'];
apiKey.apiKey = 'xxx';
// Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. 'Token' (defaults to null)
//apiKey.apiKeyPrefix = 'Token'

// Configure API key authorization: partner-key
//const partnerKey = defaultClient.authentications['partner-key'];
//partnerKey.apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';
// Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. 'Token' (defaults to null)
//partnerKey.apiKeyPrefix['partner-key'] = 'Token'

const apiInstance = new SibApiV3Sdk.TransactionalEmailsApi();

const sendSmtpEmail = new SibApiV3Sdk.SendSmtpEmail(); // SendSmtpEmail | Values to send a transactional email

const sendEmail = async (to, subject, htmlBody, textBody) => {

    sendSmtpEmail.to = [{ email: to }];
    sendSmtpEmail.sender = { email: '*', name: '*' };
    sendSmtpEmail.htmlContent = `*`;
    sendSmtpEmail.textContent = `*`;
    sendSmtpEmail.subject = `*`;
    sendSmtpEmail.replyTo = { email: '*' };

    const result = await apiInstance.sendTransacEmail(sendSmtpEmail);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
};


export { sendEmail };
```

The `apiInstance.sendTransacEmail(sendSmtpEmail)` line throws a 403 error that simply says "Forbidden". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transactional account is not activated. Create a ticket on SendinBlue support. They will activate it and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
**Solved by upgrading to the new [brevo sdk](https://developers.brevo.com/docs/api-clients)**.

- Only the configuration change, so it's easy to do.

For PHP:

```
 $config = Brevo\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey(...);
        //And of course update the sources:
use Brevo;
use Brevo\Client\Api\TransactionalEmailsApi;
use Brevo\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail;
```

Hope this help.
Ps: SendInblue sdk is now deprecated.